# MUI Grid - Draggable Droppable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid

Has anyone had success making a MUI Grid draggable and droppable ? Which 3rd party library do you recommend?

Taking about something thats say a 3x3 grid

```
x  x  x
x  x  x
x  x  x
```